# Markdown link broken in new Close Votes menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, user-interface, markdown-rendering

I noticed the new slightly changed close reason dialogue today and there's a typo in "General Computing Hardware and Software". The markdown link didn't expand correctly:

[image]

Not sure how this would be fixed, but hopefully the mods can pass it on to their superiors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be fixed now. Thanks!